# [Boost::ext].SML: How to get the "real" event in "on_entry<_>" and "on_exit<_>" when using the '_' (underscore) placeholder

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-sml

**Precondition:**
I used the Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/ to run the code snipped below.

**Problem description:**
I tried to access the events members when using the generic event ('_' underscore) handling for on_entry/on_exit definitions.
This is working only for the newest gcc compiler x86-64 gcc 11.1 available on the Compiler Explorer. For older versions it throws errors.

So I tried different solutions to overcome this issue.

In my code snipped below you will find 3 different versions that can be used to test this issue.
The 1. and the 2. Version will only work with the newest gcc compiler x86-64 gcc 11.1 
The 3. Version allows to solve this issue with an awkward reinterpret_cast which I think is not a nice solution.

**Questions:**
**A)** Is my current solution with reinterpret_cast a safe solution or do you see some pitfalls?
If you see some pitfalls, then please explain them. Thanks!

**B)** Is there any other solution to overcome this issue with older gcc compilers as the x86-64 gcc 11.1 without using a reinterpret_cast?
Thanks!

**Code snipped:**

```cpp
#include <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boost-ext/sml/master/include/boost/sml.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace sml = boost::sml;
namespace {

struct BaseEvent {
    BaseEvent(int value = 200) : i(value) {}
    int i;
};

struct e1 : BaseEvent {};
struct e2 {};
struct e3 : BaseEvent { e3() : BaseEvent(300){} };

struct OnEntry{
    // Handle BaseEvent's and access members of that event
    void operator()(const auto& event){
        // 1. Version) Works only with compiler x86-64 gcc 11.1
        const int i = event.i;

        // 2. Version) Works only with compiler x86-64 gcc 11.1
        //const int i = (static_cast<const BaseEvent&>(event)).i;

        // 3. Version) Works with all compilers
        //const int i = (reinterpret_cast<const BaseEvent&>(event)).i;

        printf("[OnEntry] %s | BaseEvent related event with value=%d\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>(), i);
    }

    // Used to handle non BaseEvent's
    void operator()(const e2& event){
        printf("[OnEntry] %s | other events\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>());
    }
    
    void operator()(const sml::back::initial& event){}
};

struct TestSm {
    auto operator()() const noexcept {
        using namespace sml;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"idle"_s + event<e1> = "s1"_s,
            "s1"_s + event<e2> = "s2"_s,
            "s2"_s + event<e3> = "s3"_s,

            // The on_entry is defined to handle all events,
            // but OnEntry operator should handle the real event e1 provided from process_event.
            // This only works for compiler x86-64 gcc 11.1 for older versions
            // like x86-64 gcc 10.3 it won't work and requires an
            // awkward reinterpret_cast (see definition of OnEntry above).
            "s1"_s  + on_entry<_> / OnEntry(),
            "s2"_s  + on_entry<_> / OnEntry(),
            "s3"_s  + on_entry<_> / OnEntry()
        );
    }
};

}  // namespace

int main() {
    sml::sm<TestSm> sm;
    sm.process_event(e1{});
    sm.process_event(e2{});
    sm.process_event(e3{});
}
```

Comment: The Boost State Machine Library has nothing to do with the programming language Standard ML, [tag:sml].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for question A

If you remove the following overload, then invalid memory read would happen.
That is a pitfall.

```
// Used to handle non BaseEvent's
void operator()(const e2& event){
    printf("[OnEntry] %s | other events\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>());
}
```

### Answer for question B

#### C++17

You can solve the problem using `if constexpr` and type_traits `std::is_base_of_v` meta function.

This is a solution code:

```
void operator()(const auto& event){
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<BaseEvent, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(event)>>) {
        const int i = event.i;
        printf("[OnEntry] %s | BaseEvent related event with value=%d\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>(), i);
    }
}
```

I think that using template instead of `auto` parameter type is simpler.
See the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void operator()(const T& event){
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<BaseEvent, T>) {
        const int i = event.i;
        printf("[OnEntry] %s | BaseEvent related event with value=%d\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>(), i);
    }
}
```

I've checked my solution work with gcc 7.3.0 and later, and clang 3.9.1 or later.

- gcc

  - https://wandbox.org/permlink/qOzbhGxAvZgsC7Z0
- clang

  - https://wandbox.org/permlink/y45yTz8Mq1CrFQGE

#### C++14

In C++14, you need to replace `if constexpr` wifh SFINAE.
So the code is as follows:

```
// Handle BaseEvent's and access members of that event
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BaseEvent, T>::value> 
operator()(const T& event){
    const int i = event.i;
    printf("[OnEntry] %s | BaseEvent related event with value=%d\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>(), i);
}

// Used to handle non BaseEvent's
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<BaseEvent, T>::value> 
operator()(const T& event){
    printf("[OnEntry] %s | other events\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>());
}
```

- https://wandbox.org/permlink/ACV084Yq9NL8cest

#### NOTE

- clang 10.0.0 and later works well with option 1.

  - https://wandbox.org/permlink/NPUFq5ilDvfmU3jS

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great feedback!
It tried that and it worked well with -std=c++17, when using c++14 I got some trouble due to the newly introduces if-constexpr.
I tried several other solutions based on your idea of std::is_base_of.
See my answer below.

Comment: If you use C++14, `if constexpr` can be replaced with SFINAE. I updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect, you safed my day! This is a nice and solution.
I highly appreciate your experience in template programming.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for question B

Based on the answer from Takatoshi Kondo and the lack of using if-constexpr for c++14 standard, I found another solution that is quite similar to the one of Takatoshi.

The following code snipped has to replace the whole OnEntry struct from the original question:

```
template <bool B>
struct Handle{ };

// Handle's BaseEvent and access members of that event
template<>
struct Handle<true>
{
    void operator()(const BaseEvent&  event)
    {
        const int i = event.i;
        printf("[OnEntry] %s | BaseEvent related event with value=%d\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>(), i);
    }
};

// Handles non-BaseEvent's
template <>
struct Handle<false>
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(const T&  event) {
        printf("[OnEntry] %s | non-BaseEvent related event\n", sml::aux::get_type_name<decltype(event)>());
    }
};

struct OnEntry{     
    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& event){
         Handle<std::is_base_of<BaseEvent, T>::value>()( event );
    }
};
```

The only thing I'm unhappy with is that I can't move this explicit template specialization into the OnEntry struct due to compiler error message "error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope".

Comment: @Takatoshi Kondo, @ All:
If you have other solutions to overcome the compiler error and using c++14 standard to solve my follow up problem, then please let me know.
Thanks!